# Difference between Q.defer() & Promise()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to understand why following code is behaving differently with Q.defer() and Promise()

> **Case 1** : When I'm using Q.defer()

```
getDocument(id)
.then(function (response) {
   console.log('in first then')
   return 'from two';
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response)
});

var getDocument=function(){
  var b = Q.defer();
    b.resolve('from getDocument'); // here will do some async operation..this is just an example
  return b.promise;
}
```

Output:

```
in first then
undefined
```

> **Case 2**: using Promise()

```
getDocument(id)
.then(function (response) {
   console.log('in first then')
   return 'from two';
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response)
});

var getDocument=function(){
  return Promise.resolve('from getDocument');
}
```

Output:

```
in first then        
from two
```

> **Question**

1. Why there is a difference in output?
2. I know that Q.defer is an anti-pattern but then how to choose when to use what?

Comment: Could you provide a plunkr/fiddle..? I doubt 1st output shouldn't be having `undefined` in 2nd `console.log`

Comment: Which version of Q ... because `v1` works fine

Comment: _"I know that Q.defer is an anti-pattern but then how to choose when to use what?"_ Use the Promise constructor to wrap non-Promise asynchronous operations in a promise. Use `.defer` in situations when using the Promise constructor would be very complicated or awkward and `.defer` would be more elegant (this should be almost never).

Comment: @JLRishe: can you explain with an example

Comment: are you using this Q - https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Comment: @ Jaromanda X : yes

Comment: You _must_ be using a really old or bastardized Q... your code using `Q.defer` is not at all working like promises are supposed to. Or your simplified post is lacking a relevant detail.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/j5s1612e/. It looks like newer versions of Q don't support `Q.defer()` so the first example doesn't run at all with newer versions of Q.

Comment: @ JLRishe : which version of Q you have used

Comment: It works with 1.0.1 and 1.4.1. I think what I said about newer versions not supporting `.defer()` was incorrect. It was failing for a different reason.

Comment: @RishiTiwari I don't have an example of a good situation for `.defer()`. Rule of thumb is: don't use it.

Comment: @ JLRishe : So for which version it is failing..? 1.4.1 or ..?

Comment: @RishiTiwari 2.0.3, but that seems to be because it uses a module loader (at least the one on cdnjs seems to be set up that way).

Comment: Actually I'm using a module loader(common js) to load my dependency such as Q....When I'm adding the referece of the Q library directly on my HTML page everything is working fine..but when m loading it through a module loader its not working

Answer (score 2):

In fact, both examples are returning the same result (the same order). Check this codepen [Example](http://codepen.io/tuliofaria/pen/GrpqPE?editors=1111)

```
var getDocument=function(){
  var b = Q.defer();
    b.resolve('Q from getDocument'); // here will do some async operation..this is just an example
  return b.promise;
}

getDocument(1)
.then(function (response) {
   console.log('Q in first then')
   return 'Q from two';
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response)
});

var getDocumentP=function(){
  return Promise.resolve('P from getDocument');
}

getDocumentP(1)
.then(function (response) {
   console.log('P in first then')
   return 'P from two';
}).then(function (response) {
   console.log(response)
});
```

2) You can see here some uses of Q.defer: [Q.defer you´re doing it wrong](http://www.codelord.net/2015/09/24/$q-dot-defer-youre-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: `The diffence happens because the promises one was built wrongly` - except it's the Q one that is wrong

Comment: I don't see anything wrong there...I know that one should not use deferred pattern if you already have a promise to return..but just for my understanding want to know why the two approaches giving different outputs

Comment: The strange thing. I´m testing your code inside a codepen and with Q matches the Promises one: http://codepen.io/tuliofaria/pen/GrpqPE?editors=1111

Comment: Actually I'm using a module loader(common js) to load my dependency such as Q....When I'm adding the referece of the Q library directly on my HTML page everything is working fine..but when m loading it through a module loader its not working.